# How to route/redirect my Internet traffic through another router/node on the net?

Tags: vpn, ip, router, routing

I am trying to access some content on the Internet which has some stupid geographic restrictions (access limited from a specific country. Most likely the restriction is IP based. I happen to have access to a local internet connection in the country that can access the content.

I would like to know how to tunnel my connection from my current location in country A, through my Internet connection in country B and have it exit to the Internet from there. Or more simply put, how can I use the internet as if I'm in country B while I'm in country A?

*Is there something we can achieve by fiddling with the routing rules? (static routes, gateway, ...)*

#### A few remarks:

- I know how to implement this kind of solution with a VPN server behind the router. But I would like to find a solution which **relies only on the router** in country B (no computer/server there).
- Also, privacy is not an issue (data goes out to the Internet from point B anyways), thus the exchange between point A and B **should NOT** be encrypted
- Finally, to avoid any remarks, let's assume that **bandwidth is NOT an issue**

Comment: Your question seems to contradict itself.. you say "how to use/be seen with my IP from country B while connected from country A" but also say "(access limited from a specific country): most likely, the restriction is IP based". Without really knowing if it is possible, if it was possible, since your IP remains the same but the restriction is IP based you will not acheive your desired result regardless.

Comment: That's exactly, why I want to involve point B: the content C cannot directly be accessed from A, but it can be accessed from B, and A and B can talk together...

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible. Your router's interface that is connected to the service provider's network can very likely only talk to the service provider's router. From there, you have no control over how they route your traffic.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I've never used Hamachi before, but I believe it involves some sort of client to be installed on a computer, which I explicitly excluded!! And in this case (with a server at B), I already know how to do it using a VPN server (OpenVPN for instance), or more simply with a SSH tunnel, and I wouldn't be asking questions here!!

Comment: Okay, I will remove my suggested workarounds, good luck.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I use the internet as if I'm in country B while I'm in country
>   A?
>
> [...]
>
> I know how to implement this kind of solution with a VPN server behind
>   the router. But I would like to find a solution which relies only on
>   the router in country B (no computer/server there).

This can be done, but depends on the gateways at both offices. The quickest way to do it would be rewrite rules at the gateways. From Country A's gateway, traffic can be forwarded to Country B's firewall/gateway. Country B can receive all traffic from Country A's router, and then rewrite the request with its own IP as the destination, maintaining a session with Country A's router. Basically Country A's router is in essency a transparent proxy of sorts.

You'll need some gritty access to firewall and routing rules on both firewalls and you won't likely be able to do this is you have mere SMB equipment. You'll probably want to use some *nix based equipment so you can have access to iptables or pf.

As for the *specifics* of how to do this, that would be beyond the scope of this Q/A. As you design the solution, you'll need to keep coming back with very specific, tighyly scoped questions for each component of your architecture.